# Why is this expression illegal in querySelectorAll

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

Why is it illegal to use el.querySelectorAll with a selector that starts with '>'? What's a simple alternative solution?

```
var el = document.createElement('div');

el.querySelector('> div');
```

This code above will produce a DOM Exception 12. Solution must avoid using jquery, which does support this without error. Zepto solutions can be provided, as this is not supported in Zepto.

When the selector does not start with '>' it is valid:

```
el.querySelectorAll('div > div');
```

Comment: Use `.children` or `.childNodes`

Comment: You are asking for the direct descendant of the selector on the left, so "x > y" makes sense, and "> y" does not.

Comment: @lossleader The point is that the OP is confused because jQuery **does** support this selector, because it does more than just pass it to `querySelector` - it parses it and determines the path it needs to take for it to work

Comment: he has specified he doesn't want to use jquery.. so he'd better learn valid css. The jquery documents themselves explain what is an extension.

Comment: @lossleader Sure they do - `Solution must avoid using jquery, which does support this without error.`

Comment: Didn't you mean ```.querySelector('* > div');```? Or something like that?

Comment: @Nux But then the result wouldn't be **immediate** children, which is what `> div` selector does in jQuery. It would find all divs that are children

Comment: Oh, so you mean something like 'this > div'. Interesting.

Comment: Note that this limitation only exists in the original [Selectors API spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api). In [level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2), there is a proposal to allow selector strings to start with a combinator in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

`document.querySelectorAll` expects a string containing one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.

`'> div'` is not a valid css selector.

`>` is a Child combinator. A child combinator describes a childhood relationship between two elements.

`'> div'` has only one element.
`' div >'` would not work too.

For more info see

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll
- http://easy-css.appspot.com/?chap=chap-4-7-2&prev=35&next=37&current=36
- http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators

Answer (score 0):

```
element = baseElement.querySelector(selectors)
```

`selectors` needs to follow standard css syntax. So, even though `querySelector` is a method of an element, the `selectors` argument must form a valid css-selector; that is, one that you can use in a stylesheet.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I have a feeling that OP is just looking for

```
el.querySelector('body > div');
```

Answer (score -1):

As a solution using Zepto:

```
$(el.childNodes).find('div')
```

If you just want all direct descendant nodes though and not a 'div' descendant, then this approach probably wouldn't help, as using .find('*') would provide more than direct descendants.

As described in the other answer, a selector using '>' needs to have a selector expression preceding it, and one following it (ie 'div > div').

Comment: What exactly does Zepto's `.find()` method do in this case? Is it different from jQuery's `.find()`?

Comment: That doesn't answer your own question

Comment: @Vincent McNabb: Well it does - partially - "Zepto solutions can be provided, as this is not supported in Zepto." Doesn't answer the why, though.

Comment: A Zepto solution to what?

Comment: @Vincent McNabb: You may want to comment to that effect on the question then.

Comment: Well the fact remains. This answer doesn't answer ANY part of the question. It provides a Zepto solution to an unasked question.

Comment: It provides a solution to '> div', does it not?

Comment: @TimLind Technically, it only says "Why?", not "What is a way to get `document.querySelector("> div");` working?"

Comment: Right, I've updated but I did originally say: 'the solution must ...', so that was kind of implicit guys ;)